# Store multiple userInfo in in local notification

Tags: iphone, uilocalnotification

I am creating a UILocalNotification and I need to set multiple userInfo to this, how can i do this?

```
    // Create a new notification

    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    UILocalNotification *alarm = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    alarm.fireDate = date;        
    alarm.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
    alarm.alertBody = msg;        
    alarm.alertAction = @"View";            
    alarm.repeatInterval = NSYearCalendarUnit;
    alarm.soundName=@"happyBirthday.wav";
    alarm.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;    

   NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:detailperson forKey:@"msg"];
   NSDictionary *userDictName = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:detailperson2 forKey:@"name"];

   alarm.userInfo = userDict;
   alarm.userInfo = userDictName;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple objects in a dictionary, so long as the keys are all different:

```
NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:detailperson, @"msg", detailperson2, @"name", nil];

alarm.userInfo = userDict;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use the combine two dictionary combine with single Dictionary and then the that dictionary set into the user info.

```
        NSDictionary *dic=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:dic1,@"first",dic2,@"second", nil];

       alarm.userInfo=dic
```